# SQL case with order ascending and descending column type

Tags: sql

what's the reason Ahmedabad isn't the 4th row here and what's the reasoning behind the when...then... 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 100? This is from https://www.tutorialspoint.com/sql/sql-sorting-results.htm.

I'm not clear on how the numbers correspond with the ascending address, and then descending address.

[image: sql]

Comment: Don't you need to match the case for `ADDRESS` field? I mean `DELHI` and `Delhi` are different, right? The query has uppercase, the data has title case...

Comment: Can you tell me, what is written in your post?

Comment: I've updated the post about wanting clarity around the numbers and ascending / descending address

Comment: the author wanted to demonstrate how ordering with a case when works, only he can answer why this order

Comment: Unless you have a very unusual setting on your database, the query you’ve given would not produce the result you’ve shown; as mentioned already, string comparisons are normally case-sensitive. Even if you have managed to set up case-insensitive comparisons, you might have leading/trailing spaces, non-printing characters, etc in your  data that might affect the result

Comment: Looks like a mistake in the article

Comment: @NickW - RE: "string comparisons are normally case-sensitive" - this depends heavily on DBMS. In SQL Server very few people opt for a case sensitive collation

Answer (score -1):

Nope, the article is correct but their data set and their queries are not a quite good match. That is why some masters(Tanel Pöder, Connor McDonald) keep their Capslock either open or not when they write SQL. They also make fun about it.

Anyway the problem here is the how the database keeps the character data or do you know how your database store the data, in short uppercase/lowercase problem. In the database their data is lower case but when they querying the database in the query they use upper case. Oracle keeps all the VARCHAR(2)' s data as uppercase but PostgreSQL and MySQL not.

[See difference:](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=ba787f216d9c175029e061f1fb3600c1)

Edit: Sorry, @Jagrut Sharma and @NickW already mentioned about the case sensivity. I just dived to the answer and then read the comments.

Comment: It doesn't matter if the database is case sensitive or not. In neither case are the results correct for the query given. The article is wrong. If the database was CS then none of the case clauses match and everything would go through to the ELSE 100 and then end up sorted in descending alphabetical order. In all of the examples the data is in title case and the CASE expression in UPPER case. Ahmedabad is not unique in this respect. very likely they are expecting case insensitive semantics and just messed up one row in the expected results. (as all other rows are correct for CI semantics)